# Logic with sets, how to solve this problem?

Tags: combinatorics

100 participants of a math competition have 4 problems to solve. 
The first problem was solved by 90, the second by 80, the third by 70, the fourth by 60 participants. No one managed to solve all the four problems. The ones who solved both the third and the fourth problems got a prize. How many participants won a prize?

It's 30, but how do I get this result?

Comment: What's about your ideas?

Comment: This is that makes you happy? Harrasing people with bad math skills?

Comment: The answer is $30$. We need your thoughts in order to help you find the answer.

Comment: Nope. This is kind of rule: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I am pretty sure the answer is $30$, not $10$

Comment: Oops ... I cannot count ... thanks Leo. @Leo163

Comment: I've actually known the answer, I don't understand the process.

Comment: Then edit the question.

Comment: I think the question must be 'At least how many'?

Comment: @HarshKumar: One might think so until one actually starts playing with these particular numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be locking up because you think it is a "type problem" where you need to follow some specific procedure that you don't know what is. But actually it is one where it's a pure numerical coincidence that it can even be solved with the given data.

There were $90+80+70+60=300$ correct answers in total. Since nobody had 4 rights, this means that *everybody had exactly 3 rights*. (If this hadn't been the case we wouldn't have enough information!)

This means that everybody got exactly one question *wrong*.

So the ones who won a prize must be those whose wrong answer was either question 1 or question 2. There are $(100-90)+(100-80)$ of those.

Comment: Yes, it is, I didn't assume that everybody had exactly 3 rights. Many thanks!

Comment: @user1030: You shouldn't _assume_ that; it's a _conclusion_ from the given data.

Answer (score 3):

$30$ people got a prize: the minimal intersection $A$ of the sets $\{$people who solved the first problem$\}$, $\{$people who solved the second problem$\}$ and $\{$people who solved the third problem$\}$ consists of $40$ people (it is easy to check it). Since no one got all four problems right, the remaining $60$ people are the ones who solved the fourth problem.

Now we are looking for the people who solved the fourth and the third (I assume these are exactly the one who win the prize). Since exactly $40$ people solved the third problem without solving the fourth (the ones in the set $A$), only $30$ people solved both problem $4$ and $3$.